# Accessing a Ruby on Rails object in a Google Maps javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to access a field in a Ruby on Rails object from my view inside some JavaScript.  Here is the relevant code in my view pick.html.erb:

> var directionDisplay;
>
> var start = <%= @route.from %>;
>
> var end = <%= @route.to %>;

From and to are text fields that hold zipcodes.  Here is my relevant Route controller code:

> class RoutesController < ApplicationController
>
> # GET /routes/1/pick
>
> def pick
>
> @routes = Route.find(params[:id])
>
> end

I read somewhere that I need to use ActiveSupport::JSON in order to access an object field...Do I need to do this instead?  If so, how do I install it and could you possibly give me an example on how to get started?  I've been searching for examples everywhere the past few days and I can't find any.

Let me know if you need any more code and thank you in advance for any reply!

Comment: Consider using the gmaps4rails gem, it wraps everything for you

Answer (score 0):

The file name should be (according to convention) `pick.js.erb` and not `pick.html.erb` based on the fact that you have JavaScript code included.

If you want to include a partial inside this one, you can use the `escape_javascript` helper to render the partial.

If you have more than one possible file to be rendered from the `pick` action, you should look into using `respond_to` such as:

```
@route = Route.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :js => @route }
end
```